# Trying to Debug C code in VSC? Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run"

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

so im trying to debug my C code in Visual Studio Code. I am on windows, ive installed cygwin and I wanted to use gdb to debug my program.

my gdb version:
GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 10.2-1) 10.2

my gcc version:
gcc (GCC) 9.3.0

I get this error message:
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". Error creating process...

This is the launch.json i am using

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading gdb to version 9.2 seemed to do the trick! :)